# If I'm printing (0,n) in a for loop, how do i make the program print the last number?

Tags: python

I'm coding a simple for loop to print out all the numbers of a user inputted n using this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    for i in range (1,n):
        print(i, end=" ")
```

I expected a result like:

```
Input:
5
```

```
Output:
1 2 3 4 5
```

but instead, I am getting this output:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: range(0,n) generates 0, ..., n-1 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add 1. The `range` function, when used as `range(start, stop)`, does not include `stop`, and it stops when the next number is greater than or equal to `stop`.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    for i in range(1,n + 1):
        print(i, end=" ")
```